# How to enforce that Static Class constructor is called in asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-classes

How to enforce that static class constructor constructor is called in asp.net web application. One way is I forcefully use the static class so before calling static constructor will be called. Is there any other way to force it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the Singleton design pattern:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

```
public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How that helps to call static constructor? Moreover you don't have static constuctor in that implementation.

Comment: The user is asking a question about how to ensure a single instance of a static class gets instantiated.  He needs the singleton design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

the static constructor is guaranteed to be called no later than the moment when the declaring type gets hit for the first time by any thread in current application domain."Hitting" a type means accessing a member of that type or a public field or just simple interrogate it using reflection API's.

Note: 
1) CLR may call this static constructor sooner but no later than what i've told you above.

2) It is thread safe (if two threads want to access a type for the first time, only the first thread wins and calls your static constructor).

3) As far as I know, you CANNOT control the exact moment when the static constructor gets called but a simple access to ANY field declared on your type will "force" the static constructor to get called.

For further info, read this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx